# How to load a file data in memory,and don't reload again. just like static field in java?

Tags: lua

I have a function :it's load a file data and build a table.
I want to load the file only once , everytime call the function and get return table in memory,don't load file again(you know io operation repeat is bad).
the goal is just like static field in java,only build once , and use it .
how to do ?

Comment: This question is very poorly stated. I get what you're asking for, but you could ask for it much better.

Comment: What you want is called [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). It can be realized neatly [with metatables](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FuncTables).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one of several ways. For example:

```
local myInternalLocal = nil

function FuncName(...)
  if(not myInternalLocal) then
    myInternalLocal = --Do stuff that builds the table.
  end

  return myInternalLocal
end
```

Alternatively, you can do it by replacement, which better hides the internal variable, and is (very slightly) faster:

```
function FuncName(...)
  local myInternalLocal = --Do stuff that builds the table.
  FuncName = function()
    return myInternalLocal
  end
end
```

The downside here has to do with modules. If this is inside of a module, then you may need to change how it rebinds the function. And of course, if someone stores the old function before calling it, they can keep calling the original version.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `require` to load the file.

Comment: I read doc of require,it means don't load require's file again . but , if method of require's file is execute , I don't know it will return directly,or execut again